# MutationObserver only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mutation-observers

Im using the following code (stolen from another topic). Im using WooCommerce, which uses AJAX when you change quantity in the shopping cart to update the cart. So im using this function to run my own custom function when the cart is being updated.

Everything works - but only 1 time. Which means that if the user changes product quantity from 5-6, the observer works and `myFunction()` runs. But if I try to change quantity again, it does not listen anymore.

```
$(function() {
    (function($) {
        var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

        $.fn.attrchange = function(callback) {
            if (MutationObserver) {
                var options = {
                    subtree: false,
                    attributes: true
                };

                observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                    mutations.forEach(function(e) {
                        callback.call(e.target, e.attributeName);
                    });
                });

                return this.each(function() {
                    observer.observe(this, options);
                });

            }
        }
    })(jQuery);

    $(".woocommerce-cart-form").attrchange(function(attrName) {
        if(attrName == "class" && !$(this).hasClass("processing")) {
            myFunction();
        }
    });
});
```

How to make the observer observe more than once?

Comment: The site probably recreates the entire form upon changing the quantity so I'd try to re-register the observer.

Comment: Seems correct! Any chance on how one might do that? :D

Comment: Well, you can either do it in change() event callback or maybe simply observe some higher parent node in the DOM hierarchy, the element that doesn't get recreated on form change.

Comment: This might be useful, already answered here
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871258/how-do-i-make-a-mutationobserver-work-more-then-once)